# get return value of jQuery get().done() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code:

```
function images(){
    $.get("page").done(function(data) {
        manipulation to get required data
    });
}
```

and I have tried to get a variable from inside the get function, using global variables, return values, and functions outside of the function. Does anyone know how I would be able to get a variable from inside the get function and return it as a value if I called `images()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it since `$.get()` executes asynchronously. The solution is to use a callback in images to process the value returned by $.get()

```
function images(callback){
    $.get("page").done(function(data) {
        manipulation to get required data
        var d = ? //manipulated data that was supposed to be returned
        callback(d);
    });
}
```

then

```
//calls images
images(function(data){
    //this method will get called when the $.get() is completed, and data will be the value passed to callback(?) in the done function
})
```

More: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Do you have any kind of example that I would be able to use?